# Robust ARIMA fitting in R

Tags: r, time-series

Does any one know if there are any functions/packages available in R 
for robust fitting of ARMA time series models (e.g., similar to the 
function arima.rob() in S-PLUS)?

I tried searching in google and find TSA package in r ,if someone use TSA package ?

Is the arima function in this package robust than arima function of core of r ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is more robust. You can check the documentation on this [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSA/TSA.pdf) and you will find that the `arimax` function in `TSA` is an extension of `arima` function in the core which accounts for innovative and additive outlier.

You can also use `detectAO` to detect Additive outlier (AO) and `detectIO` to detect Innovative Outlier (IO).

Comment: thank a lot. I want compare a classic arima model forecasting with robust arima forecasting so I want to set up forecasting model but arimax has not predict method, are you know how can I make robust prediction in R,

Answer (score 0):

You can try `auto.arima()`. fpp2 is a great resource for forecasting with r. https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html